# Spatie\Backup\BackupDestination\BackupDestination::connectionError(): Return value must be of type Exception, null returned

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api, flysystem-google-drive, laravel-backup

I'm trying to backup Laravel to google drive, I'm using Spatie and masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext
and facing this problem.(it's working fine when taking backup in local.)

main-error:
[image]

Here is my backup.php/database.php/filesystems.php/GoogleDriveServiceProvider.php:
[backup.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rOJt.png), [database.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7InNe.png), [filesystems.ph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOYBu.png), [GoogleDriveServiceProvider.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjzuE.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by making name=''(backup.php)